# Search and Count word occurrences in dataframe column value/string

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am working on a dataframe within my Spark/Scala Data Application, where one of the columns in the dataframe has huge lengthy string values with or without spaces (both scenarios are possible) , and lots of other weird characters in between like symbols and numbers etc.

```
rawDF.select($"id", $"date", $"content").show()
```

Sample dataframe (rawDF):

```
id  date        content
1   4/8/2019    CLM***120379893***John***CLM***Smith***blablabla**so..on…
2   4/8/2019    CLM***120379093***John***CLM***Smith***CLM***blablabla**so..on…
3   4/8/2019    CLM***139979893***John***Smith***blablabla**so..on…
```

I need to search for the string "CLM" in the $"content" column of the data frame and add a new column with the number of occurrences or the word count AS "wordcount" column.

```
val rawWordCountDF = rawDF.withColumn("wordcount", udf("content"))
```

I have tried a lot of variations but none of those are giving me the expected output. Can someone help me with an UDF which can produce the following output? Any help or references are appreciated. Thanks.

```
id  date    wordcount   content
1   4/8/2019    2   CLM***120379893***John***CLM***Smith***blablabla**so..on…
2   4/8/2019    3   CLM***120379093***John***CLM***Smith***CLM***blablabla**so..on…
3   4/8/2019    1   CLM***139979893***John***Smith***blablabla**so..on…
```

Comment: You should post your attempts. As well as a [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you. will do going forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [findAllIn](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/util/matching/Regex.html#findAllIn(source:CharSequence):scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator) that matches a Regex pattern (which could certainly be a literal substring) against a string:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (1, "4/8/2019", "CLM***120379893***John***CLM***Smith***blablabla**so..on…"),
  (2, "4/8/2019", "CLM***120379093***John***CLM***Smith***CLM***blablabla**so..on…"),
  (3, "4/8/2019", "CLM***139979893***John***Smith***blablabla**so..on…")
).toDF("id", "date", "content")

def countAll(pattern: String) = udf((s: String) => pattern.r.findAllIn(s).size)

df.withColumn("wordcount", countAll("CLM")($"content")).show
// +---+--------+--------------------+---------+
// | id|    date|             content|wordcount|
// +---+--------+--------------------+---------+
// |  1|4/8/2019|CLM***120379893**...|        2|
// |  2|4/8/2019|CLM***120379093**...|        3|
// |  3|4/8/2019|CLM***139979893**...|        1|
// +---+--------+--------------------+---------+
```